# PHP Locked Memory_limit to 256M and can't change it

Tags: php, ubuntu-12.04, virtualhost, memory-limit, php-ini

I've been searching over and over and can't find anything related to my issue. No matter how many times i change the memory_limit = VALUE, the php info page shows 256MB. It happen on my  virtual host. (it's where i'm using it).

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and here's what i've done so far.

Running php -i (gave me the full list and the setting show;)

```
memory_limit => -1 => -1
```

Running php -i | grep php.ini

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php5/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php5/cli/php.ini
```

I checked all the php.ini on my server as my configuration allows individual php.ini for each directory and all of the others had 128MB.

Because my php info page shows all the values i set on the php.ini for the root directory of the Virtual host, i assume that's something considered as an upper limit and can't be raised?

Thanks.

Comment: have you restarted your webserver/your php instance after your changes?

Comment: yes, restarted a few times but nothing changes. I also forgot to mention that the configuration loaded on the php info page is different from the terminal. it is "/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini".

Answer (score 0):

Global php.ini may not "trickle down" to local "accounts".

I have a CentOS cPanel server where that is the case. I set the global php.ini and it has no effect on the website in one of the accounts, even though there is no "memory_limit" in the local php.ini or in the local .htaccess file.

The default is 128M and that is what it shows when I bring up phpinfo(). I changed that by adding "memory_limit=4096M" to the local php.ini file in the web directory.

But for command line scripts, the global php.ini file is what determined their memory_limit.